# Problem to efficiently compute the Volume of $d$ anchored 4D cuboids

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-geometry

An easy still unsolved special case of Klee's measure problem with applications in multiple objective optimization is described in the following.

Let $[\vec a_1,\vec b_1],\dots,[\vec a_n,\vec b_n]$ denote $n$ interval boxes in $\mathbb R^d$. Then the Klee measure problem is to compute efficiently the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^n[\vec a_i,\vec b_i]$.

The specialized problem for anchored boxes is adding the condition $\vec a=\vec a_1=\dots=\vec a_n$. Computing the Lebesgue measure of the union of anchored boxes is known as the ``hypervolume indicator'' problem (HVI problem).

For $d=2$ and $d=3$ asymptotically efficient algorithms with time complexity $\Theta(n \log n)$ [are known](http://lopez-ibanez.eu/doc/BeuFonLopPaqVah-2009-tec.pdf). For $d\ge 4$ the combinatorial complexity (the number of boxes into which the polytope $\bigcup_{i=1}^n[\vec a_i,\vec b_i]$ can be partitioned) was analyzed by [Lacour, Klamroth, Fonseca](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.01963). Surprisingly, it exceeds the time complexity of best known algorithms for computing HVI in $d\ge 4$ dimensions, in terms of asymptotic time complexity.
*The best known algorithm for $d\ge 4$ has been proposed by [Timothey Chan](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6686177) in 2013. It has complexity $O(n^{d/3}\mathrm{polylog}(n))$.*

> Does there exists a smaller bound, i.e., a faster algorithm?

**Remark.** The lower bound for time complexity is $\Omega(n\log n)$.

---

The problem was posed on June 5, 2019 by Michael Emmerich from leider University on page [122](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=122) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/).

**Prize:** 4-D Rubik's cube.